# A retract H of G is an induced subgraph of G. show that it is isometric.

Tags: graph-theory, algebraic-graph-theory, graph-isomorphism

Let G and H be graphs. A homomorphism φ : G → H is a map φ : V(G) → V(H) which preserves edges, that is,
{x, y} ∈ E(G) ⇒ {φ(x), φ(y)} ∈ E(H). We write G → H if there is a homomorphism φ : G → H.

Let G and H be graphs. The graph H is a retract of G if there exist homomorphisms ρ : G → H and γ : H → G such that ρ ◦ γ = idH, which is the identity map V(H) → V(H).
The functions ρ and γ are called the retraction and co-retraction, respectively.

How can we show that when H is a retract of G then H is isomorphic to an induced subgraph of G.

Answer (score 1):

$\rho\circ\gamma=id_H$ implies that $\gamma$ is an injective graph homomorphism from $H$ to $G$. Then $\gamma(H)$ is the required induced subgraph of $G$ which is isomorphic to $H$.